# Configuring Serilog ASP.Net Core 3.2 with EF Core to log SQL statments

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, serilog, blazor-server-side

Previously when using the `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` I would inject the `ILoggerFactory` and `.UseLoggingFactory()` when setting up my DbContext as follows (reduced for brevity);

```
    private readonly ILoggerFactory LoggerFactory;


    public Startup(... ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        LoggerFactory = loggerFactory ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(loggerFactory));
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString($"DbDataContext");

        services.AddDbContext<OakfieldLeasingDataContext>(
            options => options
                .UseSqlServer(
                    connectionString,
                    x => x.UseNetTopologySuite())
                .UseLoggerFactory(LoggerFactory));
     }
```

I am trying to now swap in `Serilog`, I have successfully changed my `Program.cs` as follows;

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .MinimumLevel.Debug()
        .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information)
        .Enrich.FromLogContext()
        .WriteTo.Console(new RenderedCompactJsonFormatter())
        .WriteTo.File(new RenderedCompactJsonFormatter(), "./logs/log.ndjson")
        .CreateLogger();

        try
        {
            Log.Information("Starting up");
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Fatal(ex, "Application start-up failed");
        }
        finally
        {
            Log.CloseAndFlush();
        }
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseSerilog() 
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

and can successfully confirm the log is going to the log file. However, with the existing code I get the following error;

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory' while attempting to activate 'Blazor.Server.Startup'.

Can anyone advise how I can inject the Serilog LoggerFactory to EF Core to log the SQL generation please?

Comment: In 3.0 they havee  made a change to limit the types you can inject in to Startup. It was a misleading feature because it used a completely separate DI container to the rest of the app. You can still inject ILogger<T> in to your Configure method directly, but no longer in to the constructor or ConfigureServices

Comment: @viveknuna Thank you for your comment, can you suggest how I would then inject the factory to log the SQL statments?

Comment: like this `public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddSerilog();`

Comment: Hmm, ok but I need to add at the point in `ConfigureServices` in order to add the logger when configuring the the `DbContext` for EF Core?

Comment: sorry I didn't get you

Comment: If you look I need to inject into the ConfigureServices section to pass inthe logger to the Dbcontext

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215662/discussion-between-vivek-nuna-and-matthew-flynn).

Comment: Have you solved your issue?

Answer (score 7):

**Program.cs**

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseSerilog()
                .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore", Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Information)
                    .WriteTo.Console(restrictedToMinimumLevel: Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Verbose))
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to include the DB context in the following way:

```
services.AddDbContext<OakfieldLeasingDataContext>(
        options => options
            .UseSqlServer(
                connectionString,
                x => x.UseNetTopologySuite())
            .LogTo(Log.Logger.Information, LogLevel.Information, null));
```

Answer (score 1):

With the settings in the Main-Method and the CreateHostBuilder-Method provided by the Original Poster the SerilogLoggerFactory will be available for injection.

You can inject the LoggerFactory in the constructor of your DbContext-Class like this:

```
public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        : base(options)
    {
       _loggerFactory = loggerFactory;
    }
```

Then you can set it in the OnConfiguring Method of your DbContext class like this:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("MyConnectionString");
        optionsBuilder.UseLoggerFactory(_loggerFactory);

        optionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging(); // optional
        optionsBuilder.EnableDetailedErrors(); // optional
        ... // for other settings see [here][1]
    }
```